# problem in jumping to system verilog macros `define in VIM using ctags

Tags: vim, macros, verilog, system-verilog, ctags

I checked following things, tags file path is set properly.

the macro tag i am looking for exist in the tags file. task/function/parameters etc works without hiccups. i have problem only with regex.

the expression present in ctags file are

```
1. --regex-SystemVerilog=/^\s*`define\b\s*(\w+)/`\1/d,define/ 
2. --regex-systemverilog=/^[ \t]*`define[ \t]*([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)/`\1/d,define/
```

both the options does not work.

Comment: Why do you post the contents of the `~/.ctags` definition to find the tags if ctags correctly finds the macro and puts it into the tags file (as you say); shouldn't you rather post the tags file itself?

Comment: you are indeed write. I am new to tags and my understanding is limited. let me put it in this way,  when try do jump as :tag `altuvm_test_arg (works) when i try through ctrl+] it won't work.  i guess the problem in the `(tick) in the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `` :tag `altuvm_test_arg `` works, but the corresponding [`CTRL-]`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/tagsrch.txt.html#CTRL-%5D) key doesn't, this often is caused by incompatible [`'iskeyword'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27iskeyword%27) definitions, so that actually gets passed to `:tag` is `altuvm_test_arg` (without the leading backtick).

You can check the scope of keyword matching (when on such a tag) with the `*` command, which highlights the same keyword under the cursor. If backticks are excluded, try adding the backtick to the range of keyword characters:

```
:setlocal iskeyword+=`
```

If this helps (and doesn't break things like syntax highlighting, or annoys you with the changed navigation of commands like `w` and `e`), you can make that setting permanent for verilog *filetypes* put putting it in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/verilog.vim`.